# What is the Life Cycle of an Object created inside / outside a Servlet? Will that object die when the session expire?

Tags: java, session, servlets

Ok, let say in my `LoginServlet.java`

```
User user1=new User();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5*60); //each session last 5 min;
session.setAttribute("user", user1);

currentOnlineUsersList.add(user1); //this is public static List
```

Now 5 mins later, the `session` of `user1` expire, at this point of time, we print out all users

```
for (User u : currentOnlineUsersList){
  System.out.println(u);
}
```

Will `user1` in the printout list?

The question is that:

Will `user1` die when the session expire?

What is the Life Cycle of an Object created inside / outside a Servlet?

Comment: Anything added to `public static List` will remain in the list until it is removed explicitly.

Comment: @WandMaker So, the objects living inside the list will be there until we stop our Tomcat server?

Comment: If it is a static variable in Servlet class, then, yes - it will stay there as long as no one removes it explicitly - or till Tomcat is killed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user object is added to the session, the session holds a reference to that object until either it is removed from the session by some other code of yours or until the session times out. When the session times out it is destroyed and any references it has to objects are released. If there were no other references to it then the user object would be eligible for garbage collection, but, since the static list has a reference to it, it is not eligible and remains in the list until either some code removes it from the list or until the servlet container shuts down or restarts. Having the session expire will not cause the user object to get removed from the static list, unless the list uses [weak references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html). Weak references are specifically for the case where you want to hold onto a reference to something, but not let that impede having that object get garbage collected once all the non-weak references to it go away.

When the servlet container restarts it should cut the old application classloader loose and let it be GC-ed, and create a new application classloader for the new application instance. If there is a classloader leak (where there are remaining references to the old classloader), the old classloader can stay in memory with all the classes and static members of those classes and everything those static members refer to.

It doesn't really matter where an object is created, it matters that there are references to that object. The object can get created in a local method and the original reference to it can go away, as long as there are references to it it sticks around and isn't garbage-collected.

Comment: Will Web server automatically clean the Garbage for us? What will happen if the object still stay there forever (is there anything bad that will happen)?